# create list of dictionaries from two lists using for loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists:

```
providers = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
ips = ["100.12.23.34", "199.134.3.01", "123.143.2.34", "154.234.4.66"]
```

I want the output to look like:

```
[{'provider_name':'a', 'server':'100.12.23.34'},.....]
```

How do i do this in python using for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option without any zip:

```
providers = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
ips = ["100.12.23.34", "199.134.3.01", "123.143.2.34", "154.234.4.66"]

[ {'provider_name': providers[i], 'server': ips[i] } for i in range(len(ips)) ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy to follow solution. For more reading on the zip method if necessary [click here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip).

```
new = []

for i, j in zip(providers, ips):
    new.append({"provider_name": i, "server": j})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
>>> providers = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> ips = ["100.12.23.34", "199.134.3.01", "123.143.2.34", "154.234.4.66"]
>>> [{'provider_name':x, 'server':y} for x,y in zip(providers,ips)]
[{'provider_name': 'a', 'server': '100.12.23.34'}, {'provider_name': 'b', 'server': '199.134.3.01'}, {'provider_name': 'c', 'server': '123.143.2.34'}, {'provider_name': 'd', 'server': '154.234.4.66'}]
>>>
```